# Оптимизация кода на JavaScript и CSS для сайта на Wordpress согласно требованиям google pagespeed insights?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, highload

У меня есть один сайт, сделанный на Wordpress. Хочу получить высокую оценку скорости сайта в [Google PageSpeed Insight](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=ru). И там есть такая рекомендация - **Удалите из верхней части страницы код JavaScript и CSS, блокирующий отображение**. Как мне выполнить эту рекомендацию для Wordpress? Буду очень признателен за любые дельные советы!

Answer (score 3):

В общем мучился я с этим полгода и выявил рекомендации для оптимизации wordpress:

1) Включить кеш

2) Оптимизировать графику(Библиотка Image Magic)

3) Включить Gzip

4) Перенести js в footer И сделать асинхронную загрузку

5) Вынести  основной CSS в header нативно, остальной грузить асинхронно.

Вот примеры.
Wordpress

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=ru&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwob.su%2Fblog%2F&tab=desktop

SantaFox

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=ru&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwob.su%2F

Случай не идеальный, там еще работать, но зеленая строка уже есть.

Comment: Привет. Вы в правке добавили в заголовок наименование метки [tag:unity3d]. Так делать не нужно, для того и существуют метки, чтобы не перегружать заголовок. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/51713

Comment: Спасибо, учту на будущее =)

Comment: кстати, у вас довольно нередки отклоненные правки. Уведомления об этом не приходят, но вы можете самостоятельно прочитать причины по каждой проверке здесь: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/180813/vasilyuk-dmitry?tab=activity&sort=suggestions